# SPARQL - Query all data properties without upper-level-properties

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology

I'd like to query all data properties of a specific individual.

### My data properties defined in the Ontology

In my ontology I have defined trees of data properties.

[image: See Protege Screenshot: Data Properties]

### The target individual to be queried

My target individual is in my owl defined as following:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.owl.de/ontology/i40component-01#I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.owl.de/ontology/i40component-01#Manifest"/>
    <decription rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">An example work cell.</decription>
    <ele rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">35.0</ele>
    <lat rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">52.518611</lat>
    <lon rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">13.376111</lon>
    <name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">I40 Work Cell 1</name>
    <production_date rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">2012-12-31T23:57:00</production_date>
    <uuid rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf</uuid>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

In Protege it looks like:
[image: See Protege Screenshot: Individual in Protege]

### Aimed result

The goal/aim is to query all defined data properties shown in Protege or in the OWL snippet. The expected result for this query should be:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| I40Component                                                                       | dataProperty             | datatypeValue                          |
==========================================================================================================================================================
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:uuid             | "e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf" |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:production_date  | "2012-12-31T23:57:00"                  |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:name             | "I40 Work Cell 1"                      |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:lon              | "13.376111"                            |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:lat              | "52.518611"                            |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:ele              | "35.0"                                 |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:decription       | "An example work cell."                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### My current SPARQL query and the result

My current test method looks like the following. It builds and execute a SPARQL query.

```
@Test
public void showDataPropertiesOfWholeManifest() {
    SelectBuilder sb = new SelectBuilder() //Building a Query template
            .addPrefix("i40comp", owl.getI40NameSpace() + "#")
            .addPrefix("rdfs", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#")
            .addPrefix("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#")
            .addPrefix("owl", "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#")
            .addPrefix("rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");

    //Define Variables      
    sb.addVar("?I40Component");
    sb.addVar("?dataProperty");
    sb.addVar("?datatypeValue");

    //Find Individuals for Type "Manifest"
    sb.addWhere("?I40Component", "rdf:type", URI.generateSparqlURI(I40VOC.Classes.AssetAdministrationShell.Manifest));

    //Find Individual with UUID "e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf"
    sb.addWhere("?I40Component", "i40comp:uuid", "e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf"); //Filter I40Component

    //Get all properties of this individual
    sb.addWhere("?dataProperty", "?", "owl:DatatypeProperty");

    // Results preparation
    sb.addWhere("?I40Component", "?dataProperty", "?datatypeValue");

    //Filters blanks and literals
    try {
        sb.addFilter("!isBlank(?datatypeValue)");
        sb.addFilter("isLiteral(?datatypeValue)");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Build query and print result
    Query q = sb.build();
    executeSPARQLqueryAndPrintResult(q);
}
```

Or again as Query String:

```
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  i40comp: <http://www.owl.de/ontology/i40component-01#>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT  ?I40Component ?dataProperty ?datatypeValue
WHERE
  { ?I40Component
              rdf:type       i40comp:Manifest ;
              i40comp:uuid   "e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf" .
    ?dataProperty
              ?              owl:DatatypeProperty .
    ?I40Component
              ?dataProperty  ?datatypeValue
    FILTER ( ! isBlank(?datatypeValue) )
    FILTER isLiteral(?datatypeValue)
  }
```

---

Unfortunately the result is not the result I need. See following result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| I40Component                                                                       | dataProperty             | datatypeValue                          |
==========================================================================================================================================================
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:uuid             | "e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf" |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:production_date  | "2012-12-31T23:57:00"                  |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:name             | "I40 Work Cell 1"                      |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:lon              | "13.376111"                            |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:lat              | "52.518611"                            |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:ele              | "35.0"                                 |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:decription       | "An example work cell."                |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:aas              | "52.518611"                            |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:manifest         | "52.518611"                            |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:aas              | "An example work cell."                |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:aas              | "I40 Work Cell 1"                      |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:aas              | "2012-12-31T23:57:00"                  |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:aas              | "35.0"                                 |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:manifest         | "35.0"                                 |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:aas              | "e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf" |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:aas              | "13.376111"                            |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:manifest         | "13.376111"                            |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:manifest         | "e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf" |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:manifest         | "2012-12-31T23:57:00"                  |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:manifest         | "An example work cell."                |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:manifest         | "I40 Work Cell 1"                      |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:wpt_gps_location | "52.518611"                            |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:wpt_gps_location | "35.0"                                 |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:wpt_gps_location | "13.376111"                            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Somehow the SPARQL query goes to the "upper level data properties" and select them also as result and prints the value of the real sub-property. 
Like:

```
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:wpt_gps_location | "52.518611"                            |
```

Which should be normally:

```
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:lat              | "52.518611"                            |
```

Maybe one of you can explain me why this happens and can also support me with the improvement of the query to get the aimed result.

Comment: that line is clearly wrong: `sb.addWhere("?dataProperty", "?", "owl:DatatypeProperty");` - the query pareser will fail for sure. It must be `rdf:type` as predicate

Comment: what is wrong with query result? I mean, it's obviously due to inference. So my guess - and you didn't show the type of model you used - you're using an inference model. Am I right? Do you know what inference aka reasoning is? I you only want the asserted data the simplest case is to use a default model and load the data into this one

Comment: by the way, RDF and OWL support more datatypes than just `xsd:string` ...

Comment: Hi @AKSW, (1.) regarding your first comment: I got no error messages and the results has not changed after I changed the "?" to "rdf:type". But thank you for the hint, in future I will use "rdf:type". (2.) Regarding your second command. Thanks a lot for this message, you were completely right. I changed `OntModel mONT = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();` to `mONT= ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();` and then I got the aimed result. I'm new in the Ontologies area and had to learn the inference stuff. (3.) Regarding your third comment: Thank you! I will change the datatypes for e.g. GPS coords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Solution

The needed hint came from AKSW:

> what is wrong with query result? I mean, it's obviously due to
>   inference. So my guess - and you didn't show the type of model you
>   used - you're using an inference model. Am I right? Do you know what
>   inference aka reasoning is? I you only want the asserted data the
>   simplest case is to use a default model and load the data into this
>   one – AKSW

The problem was the use of an inference model (inference aka reasoning) in Jena:

```
OntModel mONT = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
```

Such models deliver also interfering data.

To get only asserted data as aimed in my scenario, the easiest way is it to use simply a default model instead of an Ontology model (`Model` instead of `OntModel`):

```
Model mONT = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()
```

Through this change I only get asserted data and the aimed result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| I40Component                                                                       | dataProperty            | datatypeValue                          |
=========================================================================================================================================================
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:lon             | "13.376111"                            |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:ele             | "35.0"                                 |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:decription      | "An example work cell."                |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:name            | "I40 Work Cell 1"                      |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:production_date | "2012-12-31T23:57:00"                  |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:uuid            | "e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf" |
| i40comp:I40Component_e41bdfaa-7163-46ed-8cb3-350fa226bbaf_I40WorkCell1_AASmanifest | i40comp:lat             | "52.518611"                            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you AKSW!